# Select Last of each ID in Excel

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel with multiple map units, and a value corresponding to each map unit. However map units are listed multiple times, and I only want that last value for each map unit to be selected.

For example:

MAPUNIT = 1 ; VALUE = 2

MAPUNIT = 1 ; VALUE = 4

MAPUNIT = 1 ; VALUE = 1

MAP UNIT =2 ; VALUE = 3

MAPUNIT=2 ; VALUE = 4

MAPUNIT = 3; VALUE = 2

MAPUNIT = 4; VALUE =1

MAPUNIT = 4; VALUE = 5

And I want the output to look like:

MAPUNIT =1 ; VALUE = 1

MAPUNIT = 2; VALUE = 4

MAPUNIT =3 ; VALUE = 2

MAPUNIT =4 ; VALUE = 5

Is there a formula in Excel or a SQL query to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't the last entry for `MAPUNIT = 1` be `VALUE = 1`?

Comment: Also, are the `MAPUNIT`s always in ascending order?

Comment: Sorry thank you, careless mistake. I adjusted it to be VALUE = 1. Yes the map units are always in ascending order.

Comment: Follow-up: Are the words `MAPUNIT` and `VALUE` actually in the cells, or were you just showing that for clarity?

Comment: They were just for clarity -- the names of the columns are "mukey" and "Weight_Calc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think this should work. My assumptions are that the cells you reference above are in `A1:B9` (with column headers in row 1) and I'm putting the unique `MAPUNIT` numbers in column `E` and the formulas are going into column `F`.

```
=INDEX(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$9,0),0,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,E2),1),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,E2))
```

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

EDIT:

In case your list of unique `MAPUNIT` values is much longer, you can make the list by copying the original column and then doing a remove duplicates operation.

Comment: I must clarify, the values that I posted for my map units are more complicated, I just listed those 8 example values for simplification. My actual values range from approximately 510000 to 1000000 and do not necessarily cover every single value between. Is there a way to simply work off of the given map units, rather than creating a new column with unique map units? -- my map unit column, for example, begin with 516510,516511,516513,516519, 516519, 516522, etc... Apologies for the complications. Your code seems like it will send me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. There are probably many ways to do it, but the quickest way I can think of is to copy that column, paste it into another column (paste special: values, if they are formulas) and then go to Data (in the ribbon at the top of Excel) and click Remove Duplicates.

Comment: I have seen the edit above, and will try that first! Thank you for all your help Nicholas.

Comment: My pleasure. I will clarify further as needed. Good luck!

Comment: It worked! Thank you again, I'm so relieved to have solved that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't provide a proper example I can only guess that, perhaps,:

```
=IF(A2<>A3,B2,"")
```

*might* be suitable in Row 2 and copied down to suit, combined with filtering out the blanks in the relevant column.